# How many subnets are possible of a given mask

Tags: networking, cisco, subnet

If I am given a mask: `255.255.255.224` of `class B` then I believe that `11111111.11111111.11111100.00000000` is what will tell me the info of the network.

Say first 22 bits tells me about the network and in that also last 6 bits tells me about the subnet. If I understood correctly. So IP may vary like:

```
182.5.0.0 to 182.5.3.255

182.5.4.0 to 182.5.7.255 

.

.

.

182.5.252.0 to 182.5.255.255
```

If these are all the subnet networks then I believe that:

total number of subnets formed as 2^6 = 64

ip in each network 2^10 = 1024

total host in each network = 1022

Now if this is all correct I don't understand.

I read [Cisco docs](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/dynamic-address-allocation-resolution/13711-40.html) that I can't have subnet addressing of 182.5.0.0 and of 182.5.255.255 because they are the network address and broadcast address of both the main network: 182.5.H.H and the first subnet network and last subnet network.

Then the answer should be:

The total number of subnet networks = 2^6 -2 = 62

Total number of hosts in each = 2^10 - 2 = 1022

Now this is correct according to [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/computer-networks-set-10/) but for other problems and questions everyone just do 2^(number of subnet bits) which is correct. Then what is correct and what is the convention. Using this formula: [Example of calculating subnet networks](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/simplify-routing-how-to-organize-your-network-into-smaller-subnets#:%7E:text=Total%20number%20of%20subnets%3A%20Using,the%20result%20is%2032%20subnets.) so what is going on and where I am getting this whole thing wrong?

Comment: The whole concept of classes is basically obsolete at this point in time.  Also, 255.255.255.224 = 11111111.11111111.11111111.1110000, not 11111111.11111111.11111100.0000000. (128+64+32=224)

Comment: With 11111111.11111111.11111100.00000000, the first 22 bits tells you about the network, but it is the last 12 bits (not 6) that tells you about the host (really no more concept of subnet anymore, but even considering this as class C, that would be 2 bits for the subnet, not 6)

Comment: To clarify, we do still have "subnets" in the sense that prefixes can be sub-divided, so to speak.  But /8, /16, and /24 are not treated any differently than any other prefix lengths.

Comment: Subnet concept has died? Also in that geeksforgeeks question why the answer is total networks -2 and also what you mean by /8 /16 /24 are not treated any differently?

Comment: They may be treated differently based on local policies, but "officially" they are not  I'll post the relevant RFC(s) in a minute.  It is still worth understanding how to divide networks up (all that math still applies, sorry to those math haters out there), but the days of classfull networking are long gone).

Comment: I would refer you to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4632.  Here is a particularly relevant quote from that Best Current Practice RFC (see "Category:" at the top of the above given link to convince yourself that this is in fact the current best practice, although older device that did it the old way might still be lurking): "The solution that the community created was to deprecate the Class A/B/C network address assignment system in favor of using "classless", hierarchical blocks of IP addresses (referred to as prefixes)."

Comment: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/cisco-ios-in/156592942X/re292.html explains the how Cisco handled this.  With probably virtually all versions released in the last decade, that command is enabled by default.  To clarify that example, if the router was reconfigured with "no ip classless" (enable old behavior) that the pkt would be dropped (unless a 10/8 route was added).  There are more details surrounding this, especially regarding other vendors' handling of this (such as how to handle default route/"route of last resort", "martians", various types of broadcast, proxy ARP, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Classful networking was **obsoleted 28 years ago**, with the introduction of CIDR in RFCs 1518/1519. It wasn't a very good concept and we should leave it in the history drawer.

You can subnet any network as long as you've got host bits left to borrow. The smallest possible subnet is /31 (for point-to-point links), so with a /26 network you've got five bits to borrow, allowing for up to 2<sup>5</sup> = 32 subnets.

More generally, if you start out with a */n* network and subnet it down to */m*, you can have up to 2<sup>*m-n*</sup> subnets.

The number of usable addresses in each subnet is 2<sup>*numberofhostbits*</sup> minus two (for the subnet address and its directed broadcast address), except for /31 which has two usable addresses. Of course, *numberofhostbits* is the number you're currently left with, not the ones you started with.

Answer (score 1):

> I read Cisco docs that I can't have subnet addressing of 182.5.0.0 and of
> 182.5.255.255 because they are the network address and broadcast address of
> both the main network: 182.5.H.H and the first subnet network and last
> subnet network.

This was also true before CIDR, but now and due to the lack of IPv4 addresses, you can address any network with any IP address and this statement is not true anymore.